# how to do javascript/jQuery text effect david desandro

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

http://desandro.com/
if you scroll to the bottom of the page it says :
DAVID
DESANDRO
MADE THIS.

On hover it has an awesome effect would anyone know how to accomplish this using
http://designobvio.us/DoUs/directPro.html

e.g. PORTFOLIO

```
  <h2 id="introTopic">PORTFOLIO</h2>
```

Thank you guys so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He's using Transitions (webkit/firefox? not sure about other support):

```
#site-footer .made-this a {
  -moz-transition: all 0.12s ease-out 0s; /* this is what you want */
  display: block;
  font-size: 42px;
  font-weight: 800;
  line-height: 0.9em;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

He's also got a fantastic set of products.

Comment: The other relevant part is the `#site-footer .made-this a:hover` where he changes the `text-shadow`. The `transition` just makes it happen slowly instead of instantly.